# MySQL Left Join - Not empty or first row

Tags: mysql, left-join

We have two table,

PRODUCT_INDEX :

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PRODUCT_NUMBER | varchar(25)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| VENDOR_NUMBER  | varchar(10)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| VENDOR_PRODUCT | varchar(25)   | YES  | MUL |         |       |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

PRODUCT :

```
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PRODUCT_NUMBER   | varchar(25)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| DESCRIPTION_ENG  | varchar(500)  | YES  | MUL |         |       |
| STATUS           | varchar(1)    | YES  |     |         |       |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

if we run this query one PRODUCT_INDEX :

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_INDEX WHERE PRODUCT_NUMBER = '900338'
```

We get 3 result in this order.

```
+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| PRODUCT_NUMBER | VENDOR_NUMBER | VENDOR_PRODUCT |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| 900338         | F00045        |                |
| 900338         | F00509        |                |
| 900338         | F01041        | CSR6719-2      |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Now i need to do a query selecting all product from table **PRODUCT** and **JOIN** ***only one row*** from table **PRODUCT_INDEX**. If field VENDOR_PRODUCT is not empty for one line we would like to take this line first. If all line contain field VENDOR_PRODUCT we would like to take first row and if all line doesn't contain field VENDOR_PRODUCT we would like to take first row to.

For now i have traditional left join query (for this example i select only one product but my query is for all product in PRODUCT table):

```
SELECT
  P.PRODUCT_NUMBER,
  P.DESCRIPTION_ENG,
  P.STATUS,
  PCI.VENDOR_NUMBER,
  PCI.VENDOR_PRODUCT
FROM
  PRODUCT P
LEFT JOIN
  PROD_CROSS_INDEX PCI
ON
  PCI.PRODUCT_NUMBER = P.PRODUCT_NUMBER
WHERE
  P.PRODUCT_NUMBER = '900338';
```

This query return 3 row because they have 3 row matching in PRODUCT_INDEX.

How can i do my query?

**EDIT 2 :**

Here is my complete query right now :

```
SELECT
  P.*,
  IP.master AS MASTER_PACK,
  IP.inner AS INNER_PACK,
  PO.INFO1,
  PO.INFO2,
  PO.INFO3,
  PO.INFO4,
  PO.INFO5,
  PO.INFO6,
  PO.INFO7,
  PO.INFO8,
  PO.INFO9,
  PO.INFO10,
  PO.INFO11,
  PO.INFO12,
  PO.MEMO_ENG1,
  PO.MEMO_FR1,
  PO.FLAGS1,
  PO.MEMO_ENG2,
  PO.MEMO_FR2,
  PO.FLAGS2,
  PO.MEMO_ENG3,
  PO.MEMO_FR3,
  PO.FLAGS3,
  PO.PICTURE,
  PP.PRICE_1,
  PP.PRICE_2,
  PP.PRICE_3,
  PP.PRICE_4,
  PP.PRICE_5,
  PP.PRICE_6,
  MAX(IFNULL(PCI.VENDOR_PRODUCT, 0)) AS VENDOR_PRODUCT
FROM
  PRODUCT P
LEFT JOIN
  PRODUCT_OTHER PO
ON
  PO.PRODUCT_NUMBER = P.PRODUCT_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN
  PRODUCT_PRICES PP
ON
  PP.PRODUCT_NUMBER = P.PRODUCT_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN
  addison_intranet.ae_produit IP
ON
  IP.sku = P.PRODUCT_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN
  PROD_CROSS_INDEX PCI
ON
  PCI.PRODUCT_NUMBER = P.PRODUCT_NUMBER
WHERE
  P.STATUS != 'D' AND P.MASTER = '' AND P.PRODUCT_NUMBER NOT LIKE '%ECH%' AND P.PRODUCT_NUMBER NOT LIKE '%CARTE%' AND P.PRODUCT_NUMBER NOT LIKE '%ZZZ%' AND P.UNIT != 'KIT'
GROUP BY
  P.PRODUCT_NUMBER
ORDER BY
  P.PRODUCT_NUMBER
```

Comment: This kind of problem (or at least a part of this problem) is often symptomatic of poor design. Any time you have enumerated column names, alarm bells should start ringing.

Comment: Probably but we aren't the database designer of this system and more our objective is only to extract data from this database to import to our new system. I will keep this query like that maybe we will lost some PRODUCT_VENDOR data that is not very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation function

```
  SELECT
    P.PRODUCT_NUMBER,
    P.DESCRIPTION_ENG,
    P.STATUS,
    max(ifnull(PCI.VENDOR_NUMBER, 0)),
    max(ifnull(PCI.VENDOR_PRODUCT, 0)
  FROM
    PRODUCT P
  LEFT JOIN
    PROD_CROSS_INDEX PCI
  ON
    PCI.PRODUCT_NUMBER = P.PRODUCT_NUMBER
  GROUP BY   P.PRODUCT_NUMBER,    P.DESCRIPTION_ENG, P.STATUS
  ORDER BY PCI.VENDOR_PRODUCT desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Yes if i select onlye one prodcut from PRODUCT table.

Comment: But we select all product from product table looke at my edit

Comment: I have changed the answer  using an aggregation function and group  by .. hope is useful